# Pay U integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, integration, bitbucket, payu

I am trying to integrate `payU` to `eshop` and I can't figure out where i am going wrong since long time.
Now I'am trying to use these classes https://bitbucket.org/meritoo/zend-framework-payu-integration-library/src

Does anybody came across similar problem ? I think that it is not implemented yet, because I can't find the case how to send data to payu, because method `$this->getParameters(true)` return empty array. Where can I set parameters for payu and how ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the form,you may use for integration of PAY U,payment gatway,

```
<form method="post" action="https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders">
<input type="hidden" name="continueUrl" value="http://shop.url/continue" >
<input type="hidden" name="currencyCode" value="PLN" >
<input type="hidden" name="customerIp" value="123.123.123.123" >
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Order description" >
<input type="hidden" name="merchantPosId" value="145227" >    
<input type="hidden" name="notifyUrl" value="http://shop.url/notify" >
<input type="hidden" name="products[0].name" value="Product 1" >
<input type="hidden" name="products[0].quantity" value="1" >
<input type="hidden" name="products[0].unitPrice" value="1000" >
<input type="hidden" name="totalAmount" value="1000" >
<input type="hidden" name="OpenPayu-Signature" value="sender=145227;algorithm=MD5;signature=5fa8d94670eee6d182e930a0ccf9c2c6" >
<button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" >Pay with PayU</button>
</form >
```

you need to ensure,get all the values dynamically like the product name,price,quantity,etc. Also, check for more at

```
http://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html
```

Comment: I try it. But I don't understand that philosofy. When I will have form with action to payU, how I will save order on eshop side. Second thing is, that I want implement library above, but I can't do any progress.

Comment: take a table which store your order data with payment status,which have pending status before payment and update that to success after made of payment.